# NextJS - can't identify where state change is occurring on page component when using shallow Router push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an app. that uses NextJS. I have a page that looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { parseQuery } from '../lib/searchQuery'
import Search from '../components/search'

class SearchPage extends React.Component {
  static getInitialProps ({ query, ...rest }) {
    console.log('GET INITIAL PROPS')
    const parsedQuery = parseQuery(query)
    return { parsedQuery }
  }

  constructor (props) {
    console.log('CONSTRUCTOR OF PAGE CALLED')
    super(props)
    this.state = props.parsedQuery
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Search Results</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>DEBUG</h1>
          <h2>PROPS</h2>
          {JSON.stringify(this.props)}
          <h2>STATE</h2>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        </div>
        <div>
          <Search query={this.state} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchPage
```

`getInitialProps` is ran for SSR - it receives the query string as an object (via Express on the back end) runs it through a simple 'cleaner' function - `parseQuery` - which I made, and injects it into the page via props as `props.parsedQuery` as you can see above. This all works as expected.

The `Search` component is a form with numerous fields, most of which are `select` based with pre-defined fields and a few a number based `input` fields, for the sake of brevity I've omitted the mark up for the whole component. `Search` takes the `query` props and assigns them to its internal state via the `constructor` function.

On changing both `select` and `input` fields on the `Search` component this code is ran:

```
this.setState(
  {
    [label]: labelValue
  },
  () => {
    if (!this.props.homePage) {
      const redirectObj = {
        pathname: `/search`,
        query: queryStringWithoutEmpty({
          ...this.state,
          page: 1
        })
      }
      // Router.push(href, as, { shallow: true }) // from docs.
      this.props.router.push(redirectObj, redirectObj, { shallow: true })
    }
  }
)
```

The intention here is that CSR takes over - hence the shallow `router.push`. The page URL changes but `getInitialProps` shouldn't fire again, and subsequent query changes are handled via `componentWillUpdate` etc.. I confirmed `getInitialProps` doesn't fire again by lack of respective `console.log` firing.

## Problem

However, on checking/unchecking the select fields on the `Search` component I was surprised to find the state of `SearchPage` was still updating, despite no evidence of `this.setState()` being called.

`constructor` isn't being called, nor is `getInitialProps`, so I'm unaware what is causing state to change.

After initial SSR the debug block looks like this:

```
// PROPS
{
  "parsedQuery": {
    "manufacturer": [],
    "lowPrice": "",
    "highPrice": ""
  }
}
// STATE
{
  "manufacturer": [],
  "lowPrice": "",
  "highPrice": ""
}
```

Then after checking a select field in `Search` surprisingly it updates to this:

```
// PROPS
{
  "parsedQuery": {
    "manufacturer": ["Apple"],
    "lowPrice": "",
    "highPrice": ""
  }
}
// STATE
{
  "manufacturer": ["Apple"],
  "lowPrice": "",
  "highPrice": ""
}
```

I can't find an explanation to this behaviour, nothing is output to the console and I can't find out how to track state changes origins via dev. tools.

Surely the state should only update if I were to do so via `componentDidUpdate`? And really shouldn't the `parsedQuery` prop only ever be updated by `getInitialProps`? As that's what created and injected it?

To add further confusion, if I change a number `input` field on `Search` (such as `lowPrice`), the URL updates as expected, but props nor page state changes in the debug block. Can't understand this inconsistent behaviour.

What's going on here?

**EDIT**

I've added a repo. which reproduces this problem on as a MWE on GitHub, you can clone it here: [problem MWE repo.](https://github.com/benlester/next-problem-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, interesting problem. This was a fun little puzzle to tackle.

TL;DR: This was your fault, but how you did it is really subtle. First things first, the problem is on this line:
https://github.com/benlester/next-problem-example/blob/master/frontend/components/search.js#L17

Here in this example, it is this:

```
this.state = props.parsedQuery
```

Let's consider what is actually happening there.

In IndexPage.getInitialProps you are doing the following:`

```
const initialQuery = parseQuery({ ...query })
return { initialQuery }
```

Through Next's mechanisms, this data passes through App.getInitialProps to be returned as pageProps.initialQuery, which then becomes props.initialQuery in IndexPage, and which is then being passed wholesale through to your Search component - where your Search component then "makes a copy" of the object to avoid mutating it. All good, right?

You missed something.

In lib/searchQuery.js is this line:

```
searchQuery[field] = []
```

That same array is being passed down into Search - except you aren't copying it. You are copying props.query - which contains a reference to that array.

Then, in your Search component you do this when you change the checkbox:

```
const labelValue = this.state[label]
```

https://github.com/benlester/next-problem-example/blob/master/frontend/components/search.js#L57

You're mutating the array you "copied" in the constructor. You are mutating your state directly! THIS is why initialQuery appears to update on the home page - you mutated the manufacturers array referenced by initialQuery - it was never copied. You have the original reference that was created in getInitialProps!

One thing you should know is that even though getInitialProps is not called on shallow pushes, the App component still re-renders. It must in order to reflect the route change to consuming components. When you are mutating that array in memory, your re-render reflects the change. You are NOT mutating the initialQuery object when you add the price.

The solution to all this is simple. In your Search component constructor, you need a deep copy of the query:

```
this.state = { ...cloneDeep(props.query) }
```

Making that change, and the issue disappears and you no longer see initialQuery changing in the printout - as you would expect.

You will ALSO want to change this, which is directly accessing the array in your state:

```
const labelValue = this.state[label]
```

to this:

```
const labelValue = [...this.state[label]]
```

In order to copy the array before you change it. You obscure that problem by immediately calling setState, but you are in fact mutating your component state directly which will lead to all kinds of weird bugs (like this one).

This one arose because you had a global array being mutated inside your component state, so all those mutations were being reflected in various places.